# groupby function in rust polars dataframe exposed to python

Tags: rust

Say I have a function which takes in a Dataframe and returns a custom struct called `ResultObject` — `fn my_function(df: &DataFrame) -> ResultObject`.

I want to create a function of the form:

`fn my_function_grouped(df: &DataFrame, cols: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<???, ResultObject>` where the keys here represent the unique groups, but I am unsure how to accomplish this or what is the best way to do it.

To add a bit more complexity, I am also trying to expose this function to python using polars-pyo3 (in conjunction of course with polars and pyo3). I have already successfully created the functionality for the non-grouped version.

The end goal is to be able to do things like this from python:

```
from mylib import my_function_grouped, my_function 
import polars as pl 

df = pl.DataFrame(…) 

my_result = my_function(df) # got this working ok 

my_grouped_result = my_function_grouped(df, cols) # this is what i’m trying to get to work
```

I am unsure what is the best way to do this right (maybe the return type for the grouped function shouldn’t be a hashmap) — the issue i have is that the structure of the keys are not known at compile time (e.g., the grouped cols could be two: one of type `int` and one of type `str` and the keys could be `(1, ‘a’), (1, ‘b’)…` or the keys could be triplets, etc.

Comment: Please give an example of input/expected output.